# What is passed to the function in a Promise .catch block?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, try-catch, catch-block

What's the general difference between these two styles of handling `.catch` blocks in Promises:

```
...
.catch(e => myMethod(e))
```

```
...
.catch(myMethod)
```

What does a Promise's `.catch` pass to the received method?

*e.g. Can there be additional arguments?*

Comment: [The callback to `.catch()` is passed one argument, that being the "reason" for rejection.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, there is only one argument.

There's no fundamental difference between these two styles, except that an arrow function behaves differently than a real `function`, especially `this` will be `undefined` or `window` (depending on whether strict mode is enabled or not) with a `function`, and with an arrow function it's the same `this` as the context in which it is declared.

---

From this [MDN Catch Syntax documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Syntax):

> This `.catch` has one argument:
>   **`reason`:**
>   The rejection reason.

From this [MDN Arrow Function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although ***without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords***. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for! Also, thanks to **@Pointy** for pointing to the documentation link for the [catch syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Syntax)

Comment: *Added sources and quotes from documentation*

Answer (score 0):

In `catch(e => myMethod(e))`, you are passing an anonymous function which takes a parameter `e` and calls `myMethod(e)`

In `catch(myMethod)`, you are directly passing your `myMethod` instead of that anonymous function (in above case), which takes a parameter `e`.

So, both are same. And the parameter passed `e` is the "reason" for being rejected.